# React-intl and react-router: formatRelative problems

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router (0.13) with react-intl (1.2.0). I have this in routes:

```
var i18n = {
    locales: ['en-US']
};

var routes = (
    <Route name='home' path='/' handler={App}>
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler locales={i18n.locales} />, document.body);
});
```

And this in App:

```
var ReactIntl = require('react-intl');
var IntlMixin = ReactIntl.IntlMixin;
var FormattedRelative = ReactIntl.FormattedRelative;

var App = React.createClass({
    mixins: [IntlMixin],

    render: function() {

        var postDate = Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        var foo = this.formatRelative(postDate); //this worked before updating to 1.2.0

        return (
            {foo}
            <FormattedRelative value={postDate}/>
        );
    }
});
```

Both imperative call (this.formatRelative) and component use of formatRelative fail with this: 'A message must be provided as a String or AST.'

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Turns out my Browserify versions was old. Updating to the latest fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you answer this issue as mark it as answered?